# Parsley.js validate Sinhala Tamil (non-English characters) in addition to English alphabet

Tags: javascript, validation, unicode, parsley.js

How to validate for Sinhala and Tamil alphabet using Parsley.js
Allowing non-English characters through form validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsley.js offers **data-parsley-pattern** option (https://parsleyjs.org/doc/) which can be utilized to customize the accepted character-set. This option accepts Unicode character ranges in a regular expression.

Unicode character range for Sinhala: **0D80 - 0DFF**

Unicode character range for Tamil: **0B80 - 0BFF**

You can find the character ranges for other languages here (http://unicode.org/charts/)

After collecting the Unicode ranges, give them in the data-parsley-pattern option in  tag.

```
<form data-parsley-validate action="" method="post" data-parsley-pattern="^[@.a-z A-Z0-9- \u0D80-\u0DFF \u0B80-\u0BFF]+$">
```

Done!

You may check the regular expression here (https://regex101.com/r/hhQOwl/1)